# Partially open and modify a text file in Linux

Tags: linux

I have a very big file (~450MB) which takes too long to load completely (and save), but I need to change only a few lines that are always at the same position (same line numbers). The file is generated and I don't have control on the format.

Is there a way to read and write only those lines?

Comment: By position, do you mean line numbers or an absolute memory position? How big is “very big”?

Comment: Does the edited fragment always remain of the same size *in bytes*?

Comment: @DanielB Yeh sorry, I meant line numbers.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski no I cannot assure that.

Comment: If these lines can be preemptively padded with spaces or you can insert a padding comment so you can maintain the exact same size in bytes by adding or removing padding characters, then a contraption is possible that allows you to edit the given fragment in place. It should work until you need to add so much actual data so you run out of padding characters. Even if it works, [it feels wrong](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle). To what/whom "too long" is too long? Please make sure there is no [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/355310) here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To handle large files, you can choose one of two approaches: use a visual editor that works comfortably with large files or programmatically edit line by line. That said, a 450MB file should not be problematic for many editors.

1. [joe](https://joe-editor.sourceforge.io/) is a text editor that works acceptably well with large files.
2. If you know beforehand which lines need to be edited, i.e. they can be identified without you looking at the file contents (by line number or searching) one of `sed`, `awk` or `perl` could be a valid alternative. You might want to print the lines you are interested in before editing them.

---

**Benchmarks:** all those solutions work well in theory, but which one is going to save you the most time?

For the purpose of a *very rough* benchmark, I created a 1GB, 33 million lines text file on a KVM VPS with 2vCPU (Xeon E5-2690 @2.90GHz), 2GB RAM and RAID SSD.

```
  40s --> Joe (opening the file, editing a line, saving, exiting)

   2s --> sed -n '15000000p;15000000q' file.txt
   3s --> sed -n '149p' file.txt
  10s --> sed '149s/File/Pile/' file.txt > file2.txt
3m15s --> sed -i '149s/File/Pile/' file.txt

   4s --> perl -ne 'if($.==15000000){print;exit}' file.txt
   8s --> perl -ne 'print if $.==149' file.txt
  19s --> perl -pe 's/File/Pile/ if $.==149' file.txt > file2.txt
  20s --> perl -i -pe 's/File/Pile/ if $.==149' file.txt

   4s --> awk -n 'NR==15000000{print;exit}' file.txt
   8s --> awk -n 'NR==149{print}' file.txt
  15s --> awk 'NR==149{gsub("File","Pile")}1' file.txt > file2.txt
 4m3s --> awk -i inplace 'NR==149{gsub("File","Pile")}1' file.txt
```

- `sed` was fastest in reading the whole file and displaying a single line
- `sed` was fastest in performing a substitution and saving to a different file
- `perl` was fastest in performing a substitution and saving to the same filename

Comment: All right, this is a really good answer. Just for a matter of comparison, what specs does your PC have? I think CPU, HD, and RAM should be enough in this case

Answer (score 1):

If you can maintain the same size by padding with spaces etc., you can use `dd` to extract a part, edit it, make sure it's the same size, and write it back. See `man dd` for details (offset, block size, etc.)

If you can't maintain the same size, you'll need to open the complete file anyway, because everything after the edit has to be shifted accordingly.

You did't say how big the file is, but `emacs` can handle big files (or put differently, so far all really big files I needed to edit could be handled by `emacs`).

Comment: Thanks. Sadly the file is generated and I don't have control on the format. Regarding the size: it is _only_ 450 MB, I think it may not be that much but the text editor takes forever to open and save.

Comment: 450MB shouldn't be a problem. If you often need to do this, another option is a `sed` or `awk` script (if you can specify the position of the lines that need changing), this will read the file and write a new file.